# Rails: ActionController::RoutingError No route matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a search controller (no model) where I am running a query against the Users table. It works completely fine, but once i enter this

```
<%= link_to "Good to proceed now.", new_user_product_path, :class => "btn" %>
```

It gives me

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"products"}):
```

I already have relationship estbalished between the User and product model. I am able to access the `products#new` when I directly go to the link `http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/3/products/new`. But again, when the link_to snippet is entered, it gives the above error.

My search is controller isnt tied up with the db, it just helps me process the front end.

What am i doing wrong here? Is there something I need to do with the routes?

here is my routes file

```
  resources :searches, only: [:index, :create]
  resources :users do 
      resources :products 
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the user to the `new_user_product_path`.

So something like:

`new_user_product_path(@user)` or `new_user_product_path(current_user)`

Comment: I almost sweared. Cant believe it was this, ahah. Thanks much :)